# Why this Error occurred? java.lang.RuntimeException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using

Tags: android, adapter, runtimeexception

I have downloaded one ImageDownloader code from gitHub([from Here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader))
Now when I am trying to download the image from my webservice I am getting this Runtime Exception "ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using".

I am not able to figure it out.

And this my adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> logo_URL;

    private ListContent listContent;
    private ArrayList< TeamDataClass> teamdata = null;
    private ArrayList<EventDataClass> eventdata = null;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> logo_URL,ArrayList<TeamDataClass> teamdata, ArrayList<EventDataClass> eventdata) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.logo_URL = logo_URL;
        this.teamdata = teamdata;
        this.eventdata = eventdata;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACT)
        .build();
        imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();
    } 

    //@Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return teamdata.size()/2;
    }

    //@Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    //@Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    //@Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertview == null ) 
        {
            convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_score, null);
            listContent = new ListContent();
            listContent.team_logo2 = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.team_logo2);
            listContent.team_logo1 = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.team_logo1);
            listContent.progress_team1=(ProgressBar)convertview.findViewById(R.id.progress_team_logo1);
            listContent.progress_team2=(ProgressBar)convertview.findViewById(R.id.progress_team_logo2);

            convertview.setTag(listContent);
        }
        else 
        {
            listContent = (ListContent) convertview.getTag();
        }
        listContent.status.setText(eventdata.get(arg0).status);
        int pos=arg0*2;
        imageLoader.displayImage(logo_URL.get(pos),listContent.team_logo1, options,new ImageLoadingListener() 
        {
            //@Override
            public void onLoadingStarted()
            {
                listContent.progress_team1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            //@Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason)
            {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason) 
                {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                listContent.progress_team1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                listContent.team_logo1.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
            }

            //@Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage)
            {
                listContent.progress_team1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
                listContent.team_logo1.setAnimation(anim);
                anim.start();
            }

            //@Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled()
            {
                // Do nothing
            }

            public void onLoadingComplete() {

            }
        }); 
        imageLoader.displayImage(logo_URL.get(pos+1),listContent.team_logo2, options,new ImageLoadingListener() 
        {
            //@Override
            public void onLoadingStarted()
            {
                listContent.progress_team2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            //@Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason)
            {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason) 
                {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                listContent.progress_team2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                listContent.team_logo2.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
            }

            //@Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage)
            {
                listContent.progress_team2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
                listContent.team_logo2.setAnimation(anim);
                anim.start();
            }

            //@Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled()
            {
                // Do nothing
            }

            public void onLoadingComplete() {

            }
        }); 

        return convertview;
    }
    private class ListContent
    {
        ImageView team_logo1, team_logo2;
        ProgressBar progress_team1,progress_team2;
    }
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.displayImage(ImageLoader.java:164)
at com.huskerit.score.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:100)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1554)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1288)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1199)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:701)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:311)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:844)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using in UIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737858/android-imageloader-must-be-init-with-configuration-before-using-in-uil)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have added this line in my Constructor and its worked for me...

```
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
```

Comment: yes. This is correct. I haven included in my constructor.

Answer (score 33):

```
protected ImageLoader imageLoader;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
```

Comment: Working Perfect. Boss