# How to load Image in Image View from URL in Round Shape?

Tags: android, url, imageview

I have created an android application in that I want to display image in image view from in round shape.

My code is:

```
    private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        Bitmap image=null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            try 
            {
                URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());              
                image=Global.getRoundedShape(image);                                
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Executed";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String code) 
        {
            try
            {
                profilepic.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
    }


public static Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) 
{
    int targetWidth = 168;
    int targetHeight = 166;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
                        targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
        ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
        (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
        ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
        Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
        new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
        sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
        new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

I use this code, but it takes much load for load Image.

So, is there any option to make it fast ?

Comment: please look my answer below

Comment: what if your imageview is in circular shape and it will crop your image in circular shape itself...try this https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try below code:-

**First download universal loader lib and write below code.**

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/downloads

```
int rounded_value = 120;    

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(rounded_value)).build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(strUrl1, imgThumb1,options);
```

Comment: I tried but, it not works.

Comment: @AnjaliPandya whats ur image heigth  or width

Comment: rounded_value = 123;   try it again

Comment: above code not need to put on asynctask

Comment: I tried, it not works.

Comment: seriously bcz right now its working on my 3 project without any issue !!!

Comment: in my code cacheInMemory(true) gives error, so i tried using cacheInMemory(). But output not achieved.

Comment: it means ur using old lib file and u remove this cacheInMemory(true) then run it again.

Comment: I use, DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(rounded_value)).build();

Comment: yeah u r using old lib file.

Comment: I use universal-image-loader-1.7.0.jar, if you have new file then please give me.

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: It gives exception - java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using

Comment: ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
          .build();
  ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); this line on create method on ur application class or main activity

Comment: ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434895/why-this-error-occured-java-lang-runtimeexception-imageloader-must-be-init-w

Comment: I adding these two lines, and My work is done.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Hemant Chand Dungriyal. for help me.

Comment: pleasure to help you!

Comment: Hello @Hemant Chand Dungriyal, is there any property to display image responsive ?

Comment: reponsive means @AnjaliPandya (use placeholder)

Comment: Image is not fit into ImageView.

Comment: what is url image height and width or ur image view height width

Comment: Heights and width are dynamic. Can we set it in specific size.

Comment: fix size of image view

Comment: @Duggu I tried this library. It is working fine but when I tried to change the image. I am not able to get the new image. Can you please tell me solution to this problem?

Comment: @Rohit you're probably caching the old image.

Answer (score 1):

**Using below code I get round shape Image in ImageView-**

```
int rounded_value = 123;
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(rounded_value)).build();             
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build(); 
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);                 
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(photo, vholder.profilepic, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply border to image view :

```
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"/>

<padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"/> 

<corners android:radius="30px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetWidth = 50;
    int targetHeight = 50;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
                        targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
        ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
        (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
        ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
        Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
        new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
        sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
        new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378741/how-to-make-an-imageview-in-circular-shape) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android)

Comment: Hello @Lokesh, it is works, but it takes lots of load to load image, so is there any other option to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `.xml` file in `drawable` folder like this(my_custom_):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners android:radius="90dp"/> 
   <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="4dp" android:bottom="4dp"/>
   <solid android:color="#3F7CB2"/>
 </shape>
```

and then you can set your background to this :

```
android:background="@drawable/my_custom_"
```

Comment: @Anjali Pandya you can set radius and color what you want

Comment: Gulbahar, I tried. But it not works.

Comment: I set background is white and radius is 62.

Comment: It displays round shape in background, image not crops.

Answer (score 0):

Use rounded imageview using https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView,
Hope it helps you... :)

Comment: Hello @Richa, I see it, but how to download RoundedImageView.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest UIL library from [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and use below code:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.doctor_logo_big_transparent)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.doctor_logo_big_transparent)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.doctor_logo_big_transparent)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(125))
            .build();

final ProgressBar mSpnr = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.xSpinnr);

                    imageLoader.displayImage(imgURL, yourImageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view)
                        {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason)
                        {
                            //mHolder.mSpnr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            String message = null;
                            switch (failReason.getType())
                            {
                                case IO_ERROR:
                                    message = "Input/Output error";
                                    break;
                                case DECODING_ERROR:
                                    message = "Image can't be decoded";
                                    break;
                                case NETWORK_DENIED:
                                    message = "Downloads are denied";
                                    break;
                                case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                                    message = "Out Of Memory error";
                                    break;
                                case UNKNOWN:
                                    message = "Unknown error";
                                    break;
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.w("TAG", ""+message);
                                mSpnr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                mSpnr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)
                        {
                            mSpnr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    });
```

**Along with this, you also need to provide fixed width and height to your imageView.**

```
yourImageView.getLayoutParams().height = 150;
yourImageView.getLayoutParams().width = 150;
```

You may change the value of height and width of the imageView according to the size of image you need to display.

**EDIT**

If you do not need to display progress-bar over the imageView, you may use below code:

```
private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.doctor_logo_big_transparent)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.doctor_logo_big_transparent)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.doctor_logo_big_transparent)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(125))
        .build();
imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl, yourImageView, options, animateFirstListener);

class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```